# The text in TextField going up and down when typing TexField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have an issue, the text in my textfield is going up and down when I switch app go to other app and come back, loop this action 2-3 times, typing in textfield, and it show issue as same image below. I have check frame, size, it not move.

[image]

Comment: Share some code so as we get to know what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

If the textview's height is dynamic, set scrollEnabled to false. If not, try increasing its frame height.